# Searching through 2 tables in MySQL w/ different columns, attempting a left join - getting syntax error?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, full-text-search

The following is my statement (im getting a syntax error);

```
SELECT * FROM uploads AS U MATCH(U.title, U.description, U.filepath) AGAINST('ACTG 4160 -     
Advanced Financial Accounting new search' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) LEFT JOIN courses AS C  
ON U.Course_id = C.Id
```

Basically, i have 2 tables, one that has uploads (and i need to search their title, description and filepath) and the second table has all the courses that i also need to search their title too.

I'm trying to do a fulltext search on the uploads table with the above fields and the courses table on the title field.

I've tried the following other queries, but to no avail;

```
SELECT *, MATCH( U.title, U.description, U.filepath) AGAINST('ARTH 5180B asdfdsaf') 
FROM uploads AS U LEFT JOIN courses AS C ON U.Course_id = C.Id WHERE MATCH(C.title) 
AGAINST('ARTH 5180B asdfdsaf')
```

Thanks a ton!

Comment: And what's the syntax error exactly? Your first query is bad as the MATCH is in the wrong place. It's in the right place in your second attempt.

Comment: In the second one, i get a new column called 'MATCH( U.title, U.description, U.filepath) AGAINST('ARTH 5180B asdfdsaf')' and it has wierd double values

Comment: Yes, that's because you've put the match call into the fields list of the query. You don't HAVE to put it there. It can be perfectly fine appearing only in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first query, as Marc B mentions, the MATCH is in the wrong place. In the second, it looks like you're using a WHERE in the LEFT JOIN when you should be using AND, i.e.:

```
SELECT *, MATCH( U.title, U.description, U.filepath) AGAINST('ARTH 5180B asdfdsaf') 
FROM uploads AS U LEFT JOIN courses AS C 
                  ON U.Course_id = C.Id 
                  AND MATCH(C.title) AGAINST('ARTH 5180B asdfdsaf')
```